# ASP.NET C#: SqlDataSource with Stored Procedure and Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource

I am trying to have a SqlDataSource coded programmatically with stored procedure and with parameters. Later I want to assign this SqlDataSource to a listbox as a datasource.But I am getting an error that the stored procedure needs a parameter that wasn't supplied. I do not understand why its giving me the error despite supplying it.

The Code I am using is as below:

```
sqlDS = new SqlDataSource();
sqlDS.ConnectionString = DC.ConnectionString;
sqlDS.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
sqlDS.SelectParameters.Add("@aPara_Name", TypeCode.String, aPara_Value);
sqlDS.SelectParameters[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
sqlDS.SelectCommand = "usp_StoredProcedure_1";
sqlDS.DataBind();
this.Controls.Add(sqlDS);

Listbox1.DataSource = sqlDS;
Listbox1.DataTextField = "Title";
Listbox1.DataValueField = "Value";
Listbox1.DataBind();   //this is where I get the error saying that stored procedure requires a parameter that wasn't passed!
```

can someone guide me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Can you provide your sp code, please?

Comment: @Serge - here u go `CREATE PROCEDURE usp_StoredProcedure_1
@aPara_Name varchar(20)
AS
SELECT * FROM aTable WHERE 
 (SUBUNI = @aPara_Name)
 AND
 (SUBWON LIKE '____')`

Comment: TypeCode.String... could you try with a SqlDbType instead (SqlDbType.Varchar that is) out of curiosity?

Comment: @Serge, what would be syntax please? for .Add method?

Comment: Actually I think the problem is you have to bind your parameter to a control (or a coocki, a querystring, ...) because it'll try to retrieve that binded element's value. If no such element exist, SqlDataSource might not be what you should use (you could try using a SqlDataAdapter which would fill a DataTable).

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this approach instead?

```
var com = new SqlConnection(DC.ConnectionString).CreateCommand();
com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
com.CommandText = @"usp_StoredProcedure_1";
com.Parameters.Add("@aPara_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = aPara_Value;

var table = new DataTable();

new SqlDataAdapter(com).Fill(table);

Listbox1.DataSource = table;
```

Comment: yes I have tried to do it similar way and it works, I guess it was something with the way I was approaching, should have done it this way at the first place. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem and finally got the answer.
It's simply a matter of not inserting the "@" sign when you declare the parameter in the "SelectParameters.Add()" method. So all you would have to do is to change the following line from:

`sqlDS.SelectParameters.Add("@aPara_Name", TypeCode.String, aPara_Value);`

to:

`sqlDS.SelectParameters.Add("aPara_Name", TypeCode.String, aPara_Value);`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @kumbaya.
Faced the same issue. Removed the @, and it worked fine.

Your code at line 4 should be edited as

```
sqlDS.SelectParameters.Add("aPara_Name", TypeCode.String, aPara_Value);
```