# Changing DataSource of gridview in aspx.cs File

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to connect a textbox with gridview when user enters a text it should check with Name column of gridview  if name column contains those word only those record then should be shown. GridView already have Daatasource2 with which it showing all available records now by textbox I want to show only those records that are like with the enterd words.
I searched a lot but that did't help am getting exception 
Must declare the scalar variable “@abcm”
I already seen this link 
[Must declare the scalar variable "@Name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34899466/must-declare-the-scalar-variable-name)
but it did't help me out.
this is html for textbox.

```
 <%-- <input class="form-control" placeholder="Library Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" type="text" />--%>
  <div class="input-group-btn">
     <asp:LinkButton ID="btnRandom" 
        runat="server" 
        CssClass="btn btn-primary"    
        OnClick="btnsearch_Click" >
<span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
```

this one is for gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" Height="20px" Width="979px"
            style="grid-template-rows:max-content;
scrollbar-arrow-color:aquamarine;
           background-color:#ffd800;">
            <EmptyDataTemplate>No results found.</EmptyDataTemplate> 
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

and these are two datasources.

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:FYPConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblFiles]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:FYPConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Name], [Date] FROM [tblFiles] WHERE ([Name] LIKE '%' + @abcm + '%')">

        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Datasource2 is already connected to gridview.

here aspx.cs file code for search button

```
 public void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (abcm.Text == "") { Response.Redirect("Library.aspx"); }

        else
        {
            GridView1.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Now attaching a pic of output
[image]

the problem is am getting exception 
Must declare the scalar variable "@abcm"

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception says it all. You need to define @abcm as **SelectParameters** before binding.

```
public void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (abcm.Text == "") { Response.Redirect("Library.aspx"); }

        else
        {
            GridView1.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";
            SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("abcm", abcm.Text);
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: still getting same exception @Vicky_Thinking

Comment: remove DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" from aspx page. Try to bind this also in code behind.

Comment: still getting exception I removed this from aspx and added in pageload function in cs but did't solved the issue?

Comment: It worked thanks buddy
by changing this line
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("@abcm", abcm.Text);
to
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("abcm", abcm.Text);

Comment: Ohh... Right.. corrected the answer if some1 referred in future.

Answer (score 1):

The data SQL string contains @abc. When passing a parameter to SQL it is usual for that to be a Stored Procedure with parameters. I think the connection method you are using required static SQL.

Here's how to do it ... [ASP.NET C#: SqlDataSource with Stored Procedure and Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187581/asp-net-c-sqldatasource-with-stored-procedure-and-parameters)

Comment: I did't get your point am new to asp.net can you please explain it a bit???

Comment: OK. The SqlDataSource can be used with stored procedures (SP) but you are using it in static sql mode and that's why it doesn't work. There are more properties to set if you are using it with a SP. Here is a microsoft walkthrough which is very close to what you want.   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k10148y1.aspx    Personally I wouldn't use these controls but would separate the code into layers. You don't need to but it's good to know that there is another way.

Comment: I already followed that link Is there any thing am missing from that link in my code???

Comment: Start at the bit that says, "Adding a stored procedure". The instructions are all there. Maybe try it in a dummy page and then YOU can see what the differences between that and what you have are.